# Accessing Request.Form from HttpModule Breaks AutoEventWireUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I ran across a odd problem in a legacy project where a combination of events lead to unexpected behavior (unexpected by me anyway). I was able to duplicate the issue locally; and debug to narrow down the problem. I've detailed below. Thanks. 
Note: This is the reproduction code for test in full.

**Dev Env Setup**

- IIS 7.0 on Windows 7
- Integrated AppPool .NET 4.5
- HttpModule registration in web.config

**HttpModule**

```
    public class Logger : IHttpModule
    {
        void IHttpModule.Dispose() {}

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Context_BeginRequest);
        }

        void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            // Comment line below (or change to any other collection) while AutoEventWireUp is true - no problems
            foreach (string key in _application.Request.Form.AllKeys) { }
        }
    }
```

**EventTest.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="EventTest.TestPage" Codebehind="EventTest.aspx.cs" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EventTest.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

namespace EventTest
{
    public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Label1.Text += String.Format("Page_Load fired with PostBack {0}<br />", this.IsPostBack.ToString() );
        }

        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            // Uncomment this and set AutoEventWireUp to False - no problems
            //this.Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Label1.Text += "Button1_Click Fired<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

**What Happens**

- If AutoEventWireUp is True and the HttpModule accesses the Request.Form collection then no events fire.
- Comment the Request.Form line in the HttpModule or switch the collection to Request.Headers, etc. then all events fire.
- If AutoEventWireUp is False (and Page_Load is registered manually) then all events fire regardless of Request.Form access.

It's not an issue I need to resolve for the project, as I do not use AutoEventWireUp, but I do not understand why this happens. If anyone can shed some light on this; I am appreciative.

**EDIT: If it helps this is not an issue when accessed from Context_PostAcquireRequestState. I'm curious on thoughts since Form is an RO collection but it seems there is some modification.**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this function to your HttpModule:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication objApplication)
{
    objApplication.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(this.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
}

private void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object objSender, EventArgs objE)
{
    Page objPage = (Page)(objSender as HttpApplication).Context.Handler; 
    objPage.AutoEventWireup = true;
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my updated machine. I might have to spin up a VM back to the versions in 2013 and see if an update resolved the problem. We reproduced it on three environments in 2013.